# user exists when trying to add user to systemd-journal group

Tags: debian, permissions, users, group, mate-desktop

I have been wanting to read systemd-journal by running/using `journalctl -b` . Now if I run it as a user I get the following :-

```
$ journalctl -b
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system
      Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
      turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
```

After this I ran a grep in /etc/group to see if such a group exists.

```
$ sudo grep systemd-journal /etc/group
systemd-journal:x:102:
systemd-journal-remote:x:128:
```

then I tried to add the user to that group :-

```
$ sudo useradd -G systemd-journal shirish
useradd: user 'shirish' already exists
```

You can see what it says.

I used the id command to find which groups shirish belongs to

```
$ id shirish
uid=1000(shirish) gid=1000(shirish) groups=1000(shirish),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),110(lpadmin),113(scanner),119(bluetooth),131(kvm),132(libvirt)
```

As can be seen I do not shirish being member of systemd-journal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't use `useradd` to add a user to a group. You use `useradd` to create a user, hence the error message. Try:

```
# usermod -a -G systemd-journal shirish
```

or

```
# gpasswd -a shirish systemd-journal
```

In either case, you need to log in again to make it take effect. A quick-and-dirty way of doing this in a running shell is:

```
$ exec su - shirish
```

Answer (score 1):

The command naming is confusing. You want **`adduser`** instead of **`useradd`**:

```
adduser shirish systemd-journal
```

The `adduser` command might not be available on all linux flavors, but it is on debian.